# Apache custom rewrite rule, using code

Tags: php, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-proxy

I would like to have Apache handle some custom URL rewrite code that I have. This code rewrites the following urls:

https://www.example.com/request?data=SOMEDATABLOB

into urls pointing to PHP pages. `SOMEDATABLOB` here needs decoding using either PHP (preferably) or C/Java/whatever code. Depending on the decoded contents, the new URL may point to https://www.example.com/page1.php, https://www.example.com/page2.php and so on.

My URL rewriting scheme exceeds what `mod_rewrite` can do, so I am looking for a way to do this. Some form of PHP server-side transfer to another page would work too but I haven't found how to do it this way either.

Comment: PHP can send a 301 redirect if that's what you're after?

Comment: "SOMEDATABLOB here needs decoding" - What _exactly_ do you mean by "decoding"? There are a number of possibilities with Apache. Otherwise, what you are describing sounds like a relatively standard... front-controller pattern (in Apache) with a PHP router (front-controller). What is the significance of the `/request` part of the URL?

Comment: @MrWhite a front controller seems to be EXACTLY what I need, thank you. Somehow, I couldn't find this on the web, but once I googled your suggestion solutions came through.